# Universal pre-rendering causes empty transfer-state to get set

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am using Angular Universal, along with prerendering in my app. In my app I have the following paths set to prerender:

```
/
/about
/login
```

The following path is the only one that uses transfer state:

```
/:id
```

The odd thing is, after building and running the node server, looking at the source of *any path* I can see a script tag for empty transfer state at the bottom of the source. No components used in the root path use transfer state, or any other path, except `/:id`.

```
<script id="app-state" type="application/json">{}</script>
```

If I exclude prerendering from my build process, this does not occur.

The issue is, on the `/:id` page, where I am using transfer state, the `transferState.get()` call doesn't find anything because my `transferState.set()` call appends another script tag after the empty one, with the same id. So the `get()` call finds the first empty one. My workaround is to call remove and set in succession:

```
this.transferState.remove(stateKey);
this.transferState.set(stateKey, data);
```

Why is transfer state setting an empty state key when I prerender? Transfer state `set()` is only called in a service method that is used on the `/:id` page but empty state is getting set on every route.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by my build. Things happened out of order; Files used by the webpack-generated server.js need to **not** be prerendered. If they are you get duped script tags for state transfer because it's normal for `TransferState` to set an empty object on pages that don't use it. Once server.js retrieved the file to server-side render a non-prerendered page, it got a prerendered template with a state transfer script tag already in it.

To clarify it was my package.json scripts that were out of order. Things needed to happen like this:

1. angular prod build
2. webpack build
3. prerender

Comment: I have the same issue but im not using webpack. I dont think i have any special configuration with angular Ivy and prerender that i could tweak to fix such order.

Comment: @JeremiasNater nguniversal express-engine uses webpack under the hood - all the config is contained in it, so you are probably using it without realizing

Comment: any idea where that order could be tweaked in a project with its builds in angular.json? if you wanna answer my question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69376210/angular-transferstate-prerendered-twice-2-app-state-script-tags-in-html-and-2x